# How to send JSON without column name I need send only value

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I need send this value `'979d7929-1ca2-440b-b263-107dc02dd19d'` by jsonObject ...

My API expects json. But I don't know how to do json without name and value. I can do just this:

```
json.put("name", "value")
```

output is this

```
{"name": "value"}
```

and I need output like this:

```
'979d7929-1ca2-440b-b263-107dc02dd19d'
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to send plain text rather than json.

Comment: you mean like that {"name": '979d7929-1ca2-440b-b263-107dc02dd19d'}

Comment: Plain text is single value JSON.

Comment: Consider using a different content type. The actual structure of a JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) object is fields and their values, so you can't send a value itself without it being accompanied by a field name.